# Emoji Monotoned in CCLabelTTF

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, emoji, cclabelttf

I am using cocos2d-iphone in objective-c.

When I use CCLabelTTF to show text, if there are emojis in the text they are also colored to the color of the text and that's not what I want.

However when I use UITextView, emojis are good. No matter what color I set it to by code like

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) UITextView *someTextView;
SomeTextView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

emojis are still what normal color it should look like(not red in this case).

However there is already lots of code I use CCLabelTTF, changing to UITextView is just too hard. Anyone know how to fix this in CCLabelTTF?

Comment: C is not Objective-C is not C!

Comment: Not certain about this, but i think you can init CCLabelTTF with an NSAttributedString ... that may have better chance of respecting the Emoji specifics for inner text snippets. just a thought.

Comment: Thx! but how can you init CCLabelTTF with an NSAttributedString?

Comment: hmmm ... straight from the .h file :     `+(id) labelWithAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString;`